# Python List Comprehension, missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, typeerror, list-comprehension

I'm making a random list generator function using a list comprehension, and keep receiving:
TypeError: random_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'length'
I've noticed if I remove the length parameter the function works but I want to use the parameter. (Edit) for those who were confused, one of the comments were able to clarify what I was doing wrong, the issue wasn’t the code itself but rather how I was calling the function to test it. I’m relatively new to Python so bear with me. Thank you guys for your help.

```
def random_list(length, low=0, high=100):
    import random
    return [random.randint(low, high) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: You never use `length`. Did you mean to do `for _ in range(length)`?

Comment: How are you calling `random_list()`? A missing positional argument error most likely means you aren't passing a `length` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to not give the function the length parameter it requests. If you remove the parameter, there is no missing parameter anymore.

Also, you don't use the parameter 'length' in your code. You should switch `for _ in range(10):` with `for _ in range(length)`.
Also '_' is just a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Call you function like this;

```
random_list(10)

# to generate 10 random values...
```

Comment: This won't work. `random_list()` will always make a list of length of 10, no matter the parameter.

Comment: After I edited my code this solved my error issue